# cannot import name 'vtk' from 'fury.window'

Tags: package

I am currently using a package called 'Dipy' and the error

```
cannot import name 'vtk' from 'fury.window'
```

Keeps popping up despite me checking that the dependencies are fine

```
Numpy (>=1.7.1), Vtk (>=8.1.0) and Scipy (>=0.9)
```

And I have installed fury manually with the wheel file and just normally with `pip3 install fury`, but either way I still get this error!

What else can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- For `DIPY<=1.4.1` you need to install `fury<=0.7.1`
- for `DIPY>1.5.0`, you need to install `fury>=0.8.0`

So you need to check your version of FURY and DIPY using
`pip show fury` and pip show `dipy`

It should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to the Fury website and download the 0.7.1 version using pip. It worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).